# Executing .jar File on Startup

Tags: shell-script, startup

I'm running a Nukkit Minecraft server on my Raspberry Pi (I know it doesn't have good hardware but I'm experimenting) and googling different ways to make a bash file for Linux. I have made the file startNukkit.whateverextension. I have come to this:

```
!#/bin/bash/

gnome-terminal -e "java -jar home/pi/Desktop/Nukkit/nukkit.jar; exec bash\""
```

But there are multiple things I want to solve. First, when I double click the bash file it will prompt me to: "Execute", "Execute in Terminal", "Open", and "Cancel". Instead, I would like to run it right away without this prompt.

And because this is a Minecraft server, I can only see the results of the server in the terminal, such as who connects to my server. But if I click on "Execute in Terminal", the terminal will show and then close. I thought this could be solved by "exec bash\"" as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512055/avoid-gnome-terminal-close-after-script-execution). To keep the terminal window open.

And finally, I would like to make this execute in startup similar to how in Windows has a startup folder where any file you place in this folder will execute in startup.

Comment: It should be`#!`, not `!#`.

Comment: My apologies I didn't notice! But when I go to make the change the terminal window is blank. What else am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can put your command in `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` file. Commands in this script are executed on every boot.

Answer (score 1):

### As a `systemd` service

(*You didn't mention a specific GNU/Linux distribution, I think most common ones have systemd available though*)

If you move your .jar file to some accessible place like `/opt` then you could have `systemd` run your server after startup as `nobody` or some other low-privilege user.

In addition to potentially running without access to home directories, etc. you can also configure systemd to restart a service after failure and many other things.

See `man systemd.service`, `man systemd.exec`, `man systemd.unit`, *etc.*

---

#### `nukkit.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Nukkit Server
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=nobody
Group=nobody
ExecStart=java -jar /opt/Nukkit/nukkit.jar

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### Watching output

Where you have `/etc/systemd/system/nukkit.service` and have:

- `systemctl enable nukkit`
- `systemctl start nukkit`

then `journalctl -f -u nukkit` should `f`ollow the most recent log messages from systemd `u`nit nukkit.  Your system may be using syslog or some other facility though; in that case you could configure logging to a specific file, *etc*.